# Setting Max Message and buffer size for WCF webhttp

Tags: wcf, size, message, webhttp

I currently have a WCF service with webHttp bindings, im attempting to increase the max size that can be inputted to the service by overriding the default settings in config, i have tried doing something like

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="webHttp" >
  <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType = 
             "None"
            proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="string" />
  </security>
  </binding>

</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>

  <service name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="PrimeStreamInfoServices.IService1">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<diagnostics>
```

and setting various other properties pertaining to message size but none seems to be working, can one even change the m essage size of  a webHttp binding?
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your configuration file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a multitude of settings that might have an influence depending on your settings - try this:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeWeb"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1500000"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000"
             maxBufferSize="1500000">
      <readerQuotas 
            maxArrayLength="656000"
            maxBytesPerRead="656000"
            maxDepth="32"
            maxNameTableCharCount="656000"
            maxStringContentLength="656000"
            />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

By defining your "version" of the webHttpBinding and setting all those parameters to higher values, you should be able to get through any message size (almost).

Mind you: this does open up your system to the potential of being flooded with huge messages and thus be brought down to its knees (classic denial-of-service attacks) - that's the reason these limits are set fairly low - by design and on purpose.

You can change them to higher values - just be aware what you're doing and what the security risks are, if you do!

Marc

PS: In order to make use of these settings, you of course have to reference that binding configuration in your server and client side configs:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb"
            contract="IMyService" />
</client>
<services>
  <service>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb"
              contract="IMyService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: This does not work, it wont let me send anything larger than 64k still

Comment: Can you show your config? Have you referenced this binding configuration?

Comment: Yes i realized this was my problem, i just added the whole config up to, though when i put the bindingCOnfiguration attribute i get an exception, for some reason

Comment: I just figured out its because of my security tags there...Would you happen to know why it doesnt like the security settings there by looking at that snippet of config? Thanks!

Comment: You specified transport security, e.g. you want to use Https - this requires some setup (SSL certificates etc.) on the client. I assume that might be the problem.

Comment: Right, do you have any site with reference of how to do all that that i could look at by any chance? Thanks

Comment: "WCF Essentials" is a pretty good intro article - http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0605051

Comment: Or then have a look at Michele Leroux Bustamante's book "Learning WCF" - this is really what got me started into WCF and understanding many of the ins and outs of it all - you'll find it on Amazon or any other good bookstore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [DataContract] decorator in your model, you need to add yhe **dataContractSerializer** into your web.config

Example:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false"   httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Max Message and buffer size for WCF Rest services webhttpbinding

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="83886089" maxArrayLength="163841" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```