# WCF REST using HTTP Post message size limitation

Tags: wcf

I am using Jquery ajax() ( with type: "POST")  method to transmit some json serialized string to WCF RESTful Web Service?

so  is there a limitation on number of characters in JSON string that can be transmitted to WCF in a default configuration?

Question: If there is a limitation; how to increase the message size? what changes needed on WCF web.config?

The data I am serializing is a complex object and objects contains few other complex object as IList. I do have a working sample that "POST" the JSON data to WCF and save in SQL Server database.

But Message size limitation if any is a concern of mine.

Thanks,

P.S. keep in mind my client is html page (I am accessing WCF web service in JQuery (JavaSCript) Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When exposing service endpoint for jQuery you are using `webHttpBinding`. This binding as any other has many configuration options for limiting message size, string size, array size, etc. Check [webHttpBinding description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176.aspx) and target properties like `maxReceivedMessageSize` or `readerQuotas`.

The binding itself is not only place where you can limit the incoming message size next place is `httpRuntime` and IIS.

Comment: Thanks, also found the answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188731/setting-max-message-and-buffer-size-for-wcf-webhttp