# HTTP 400 Bad Request Error with WCF Service when message size exceeds 64K

Tags: wcf, http, service

I have a .NET 4.0 WCF service.  If I send a soap message larger than 64K, then I get "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request" Error.  It works fine all the way until I go over the 64K message size.  I have read the many posts out there regarding what to do for this error, and as far as I can tell, I have the correct web.config values, but I still get the error.  Below are the settings in my web.config.  Anything I am missing?   This occurs when communicating both to my local ASP.NET VS server and a remote Windows 2008 R2 IIS server.   Is there a way to verify or log the maxReceivedMessageSize settings, etc. that are in the service binding in real-time or in the debugger?   The service is hosted in MVC if that makes any difference.

```
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="50000000" />

...
```

...

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="IpsApiBinding" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="5000000" maxStringContentLength="50000000"
        maxArrayLength="50000000" maxBytesPerRead="50000000" />
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="ApiBehavior" name="IPSApi.IpsApi">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="IpsApiBinding" name="IPSApi.IpsApi"
      contract="IPSApi.IIPSApi" />
  </service>

</services>

<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
      <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ApiBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  />
```

On the client side, the stack track is showing...

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    ...

Comment: Do you see an error on the server side? If this is IIS hosted then it would likely appear in the Event Log with an Event Source of ASP.NET.

Comment: no errors occur on the server side - no event logs and no exceptions

Comment: Have you tried all the settings [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1189191/291687)?

Comment: Lester, yes, I think I have all those settings.  Curious, are the max.. size values required on the client side?   These are really only a server side, correct?  I have added them to the client side, still didn't make a difference.  Still wondering though. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem.  Here are the details.  I am hosting my WCF service in a MVC app.  The WCF service is in a separate DLL.  I had the configuration settings in the web.config thinking that it would read its config from there.   Come to find out, if in a separate DLL, then it will not use the web.config settings.  It was just using the default bindings, etc.

To get it to read the configuration in web.config, I used the method that was suggested in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx .  I created my own custom ServiceHostFactory and ServiceHost. In the ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost I create an instance of my ServiceHost (derived class).  In my ServiceHost derived class, I take over the ApplyConfiguration and load the config from the web.config.

It works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and also had to increase two additional fields on the binding that I do not see in your code... maxBufferSize and maxBufferPoolSize.  Not sure if this would be your issue but I know that the default for these is roughly 64k.

Sample Web.config settings:

```
<binding name="HTTPNoneBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

Comment: thanks, tried this, but still did not work.  I am going to try the tracing suggestion and see if I can figure this out.

Comment: I tried the tracing option and it said I need to set the maxReceivedMessageSize.  I have it set to a very high value in the web.config.  After research using the OperationContext, I was able to view my bindings for the web service and notice that they were all set to default values.  Basically,  my bindings in the web.config are being ignored.  I think I may know what is going on.  I am adding my services to my MVC route table using method as described here,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047485/expose-wcf-services-that-belong-to-an-area-in-mvc-app-at-a-routed-path .

Comment: continued...  I am thinking now that using this method that the web.config settings are ignored.  I am accessing the web service using the mvc route, not the .svc file.  In fact, I don't even have a .svc file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for to enable Tracing on your Service to determine the exact cause of the Bad Request. If it is because of the message size the framework would tell you clearly on which property needs to be set. In order to enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)