# too busy error in my wcf service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I create a webservice in wcf ,with these config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>

      <service name="lpz.Application.ServiceImplement.InquiryService" >
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="lpz.Domain.Service.IInquiryService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="web"/>

      </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
      <!--<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />-->
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>

    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST,PUT,DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I decided to test my service using j_meter ,a simulator for create request ,so i create a fake request to call my service with 20 thread .so i did that ,but my service working for 4 minute and after that i get this page :
[image] and after 4 minutes it works again and this process is repeated.why ?

Comment: `<compilation debug="true"..` I would set that to `false` when performance testing. It is impossible to diagnose this as you'll need to monitor the resource consumption, like network, disk, memory, cpu because all or one of those is at the hart of your problem. Use a profiler while testing.

Comment: @rene i found something that maybe can help.when my service is unavailable ,i stop my iis  and i check the url and again my service is unavailable ,so i think maybe the firewall makes this error

Comment: @rene as a another question how can i define maxcontent in my binding ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188731/setting-max-message-and-buffer-size-for-wcf-webhttp